# How to declare listview's ItemSelected in code? c#

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I have a listview in my xamarin form and there is ItemSelected and ItemTapped that later can be used in my private void. I wonder how to declare the ItemSelected and ItemTapped in code.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Static local:interactiveListViewXaml.items}" ItemSelected="OnSelection" ItemTapped="OnTap" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" Refreshing="OnRefresh">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.ContextActions>


                    </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <StackLayout Padding="15,0">

                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I want to create the listview and declare ItemSelected in code. Something like below with ItemSelected and ItemTapped.

```
ListView mylist = new ListView
        {

            ItemsSource = test,


            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
            {

                Label nameLabel = new Label();
                nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");

                Label nameLabel2 = new Label();
                nameLabel2.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "reading");



                // Return an assembled ViewCell.
                return new ViewCell 
                {
                    View = new StackLayout
                    {
                        Padding = new Thickness(0, 5),
                        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                        Children =
                            {

                                new StackLayout
                                {
                                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                                    Spacing = 0,
                                    Children =
                                    {
                                        nameLabel,
                                        nameLabel2

                                    }
                                    }
                            }

                    }

                };


            })
        };
```

Comment: why do you use code behind to define template?

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist.ItemTapped += (sender, e) => {
  // handler code goes here
};

mylist.ItemSelected += (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) => {
  // handler code goes here
};
```